# Passing date criteria from a form to a query in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

This should be pretty easy, but it's not working and I know I've done it before.

I have a Date field on a form:

[image]

Property is set to a ShortDate for the date field:

[image]

I've got some code on the back end to make sure it always gets set to the last day of the month:

```
Me.txtReportDate.SetFocus
Me.txtReportDate.Text = DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(Forms!frmRunQueries.txtReportDate), Month(Forms!frmRunQueries.txtReportDate) + 1, 1))
Me.Refresh
```

And in the query, I'm setting one of the dates to be equal to the date on the form:
[image]

If I set that as:

```
=#5/31/15#
```

I get data.  If I leave it with the field reference in it, I don't.  Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What does it do if you use `[Forms]![frmRunQueries]![txtReportDate].Text` ?

Comment: What does `SELECT Forms!frmRunQueries.txtReportDate` show you?

Comment: I went to the Immediate window and typed in ?Forms!frmRunQueries.txtReportDate.  It spit back 5/31/2015.  Yet the query pulls no results, and there are at least 2,000 records it should return.

Comment: Can you share a copy of the db which contains just that form, query, and table(s) it pulls from?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Text but Value:

```
Me!txtReportDate.SetFocus
Me!txtReportDate.Value = DateSerial(Year(Forms!frmRunQueries!txtReportDate), Month(Forms!frmRunQueries!txtReportDate) + 1, 0)
Me.Refresh
```

Further, in your query, specify a parameter: `Forms!frmRunQueries!txtReportDate` as Date/time